# PHP - Curl give me ????? with Arabic text

Tags: php, api, curl

I have the php code:

```
$text_message="تجربة";
$user_phone="xxxxxxx";
$type_sms="ArabicWithLatinNumbers";
$url= "https://xxxx/HTTP_SendSms?customerID=xxxxx&userName=xxxxxx&userPassword=xxxxxxxx&originator=xxxxxx&smsText={$text_message}".
"&recipientPhone={$user_phone}&messageType={$type_sms}&defDate=&blink=false&flash=false&Private=false";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

but i got this result '?????????' with Arabic text

Comment: You need to tell us what you're expecting to get back and _show_ us what you're actually are getting. We have _no idea_ what is correct and not. Generally, I would say that if you get a successful response but with unexpected content, you should contact the API-owners.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing here we can help with. What is the endpoint you are truely hitting? Do you own it? What is the code running there? What do you expect to see as a response? Many details lacking to make this answerable.

Comment: This could happen if the script handling the curl (`https://xxxx/HTTP_SendSms`) is encoded in ANSI or returns the result in a different encoding to utf8.

Comment: @MattClark i can't share the API parameters,(this is an API to send mobile text message to a user) it works good with English text, the prob is , with encoding to utf8 (Arabic characters)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson This is an API to send mobile text message to a user phone, i have a problem with Arabic characters.

Comment: You dont have to post your API parameters, obviously, but even the service provider, if not your own code, is better then nothing. Try [debugging CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14436877/1790644) and posting the output back in your question body to better help to debug your issues.

Comment: You could try to change the charset to something that works with Arabic characters? (I have no idea what that is, though)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson this parameter `$text_message="تجربة";' will be like this on result '???????????' because it's on Arabic (the result is a text message on mobile phone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) or [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) for your url parameters.

For example:

```
...
$text_message=urlencode("تجربة");
...
```